# How to use Gradle 4.0 in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Here is the steps I took on my Mac Mini:

1. I run this homebrew in the terminal on Android Studio: 
   `$ brew update && brew install gradle`
2. I then ran this line in the same terminal: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.0 --distribution-type=bin`
3. Then I changed the `distributionUrl` in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip`
4. I then changed the project's (top-level) build.gradle file's `buildscript` to:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
           jcenter()
           mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
           classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
       }
   }
   ```

But I still get the error `Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum`

Answer (score 5):

Android Gradle Plugin is tied to corresponding version of Android Studio. Basically you can't use 3.x with Android Studio 2.3

Comment: This answer is perfectly obvious, but not helpful. There is no Android Studio 3.0 at this point, only 2.3.3. So the plugin is looking for the wrong version. Or the plugin should not be installed. Either of those could be true, except that the plugin comes pre-installed.

Comment: Actually there is. Android Studio 3.0 is in alpha status(and so Android Gradle Plugin is.) this is why Android Gradle Plugin's version in opening snipet is 3.0.0-alpha1. We need to use Android Studio 3.0-alpha to use Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alphaX

Comment: Right. Alpha. This is the official download for 2.3.3 that's shipping with the plugin that requires 3.0. You see the problem?

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. OP manually upgrade to Gradle 4.0 and AGP 3.0.0-alpha1, and AS 2.3.3's project template doesn't refer to these versions. I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly, but If you me mean that the error message should refer to Android Studio 3.0-alpha instead of 3.0 stable(which does not exist), then I think you are totally right.

Comment: I just installed AS 2.3.3 via the official installer, and I have not done any manual upgrades to Gradle or anything else.  And yet here I am, because I am seeing the same error.  OP may have confused things, but the root issue is very straightforward -- the official installer for AS 2.3.3 installs a plugin which requires AS 3.0+.

Comment: Actually, after looking around a bit more, it seems the issue might have to do more with dependencies of the sample project I opened (which came with AS 2.3.3) than anything else.  I'm inferring this based on reading [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/294)